# Bootstrap 4 input-group box-shadow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm having is the focus shadow that you get when the input text is focused. What I want is to have the text input and the right button to show focus border.

I have compiled a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a5upvc82/3/

As you can see the box shadow not showing between the text input and the right append button, when input is focused. How can this be solved? If I understood correctly, the problem is in this part of the code

```
&:focus + .input-group-append .btn {
    border-color: #20adc1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #21dff3;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #21dff3;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you forgot to select the input itself : `&:focus, &:focus + .input-group-append .btn`  http://jsfiddle.net/a5upvc82/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add same code for the input too:

```
&:focus{
  border-color: #20adc1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #21dff3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #21dff3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is happening is that your shadow is hidden under the other element. A quick fix could be to set the z-index on the element you want to see the shadows of.

```
z-index: 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add a class to indicate which addon(append vs prepend)
you could use this:

```
.input-group {
    .form-control {
        &.has-group-append {
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;

            & ~ .input-group-append {
                border-top-left-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
            }

            &:focus {
                border-right: none !important;
                box-shadow: -0.1rem -0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), -0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), -0.1rem 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);

                & ~ .input-group-append {
                    border-color: #80bdff;
                    border-left: none !important;
                    outline: 0;
                    box-shadow: 0.1rem -0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), 0.1rem 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
                }
            }
        }

        &.has-group-prepend {
            border-top-left-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;

            & ~ .input-group-prepend {
                border-top-right-radius: 0;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            }

            &:focus {
                border-left: none !important;
                box-shadow: 0.1rem -0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), 0.1rem 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);

                & ~ .input-group-prepend {
                    border-color: #80bdff;
                    border-right: none !important;
                    outline: 0;
                    box-shadow: -0.1rem -0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), -0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25), -0.1rem 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```